# Streamreader editing too much content

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am creating a quiz but one of the options the quiz must have is the option to edit questions. The program finds the question by the question number and then asks the user which part of the question does the user want to edit between the question number, question level, question or the question answer.

Say I wanted to edit question number 4 and I wanted to edit the level of this question from 1 to 2. The program will make this change but every other occurrence of 1 in the text file will be replaced with 2 (except occurrences before question 4). Anyone know a fix?

```
else if (editing == 2)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter the new Level: ");
    NewLevel = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    string content = File.ReadAllText(RouteToEdit);
    content = content.Replace(questions[RecCount - 1].Level, NewLevel);
    File.WriteAllText(RouteToEdit, content);
}
```

Comment: how does your `content` look like? how is your `level` specified? you could try to replace more than just a number. something like `Replace("level_" + levelNumber, NewLevel)`.

Comment: The problem is that you are reading the *whole* contents of the file as a string and then doing a string replace that is replacing every instance in your file. Which is certainly not what you want. The real solution is to use an appropriate data structure (in a class) that can be serialized to and deserialized from disk.

Comment: The only way to "fix" this problem is to change all the reading and writing and replacement code. Unfortunately we don't know how you structured your file, so there's no way to give you a more specific answer. As @MattBurland has said, you're doing a string replacement on the whole file, which is apparently not what you want. Instead you need to read the file question/answer by question/answer and do the appropriate changes. Or, as Matt has said, use a data structure that is more appropriate for this, and serialization. Or, you might want to look into using a database.

Comment: What matt suggested is too advanced for myself. The contents of the file are made up by a struct with 4 strings the 4 strings being: Question Number, Question level, Question, Question answer. Here is a sample of the way the file is made up (ignore what is in italics they are not in the file): _question num_ **1** _question level_
**1**
_question_ **What is the capital of England? A: Dublin B: London C: New York D: Manchester**
_question answer_ **b**

Comment: @COYG: Believe it or not, you are wrong about it being "too advanced" for you. It's actually dead simple once you get over some of the confusing terminology and is *a lot* less work than trying to manually parse files yourself. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), scroll down to the section marked "example". All you do is stick some attributes on the class you want to serialize, create an instance of the `DataContractSerializer` passing in your type and then either `WriteObject` or `ReadObject`.